# Failure importing CSV file lines

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I'm trying to import a CSV file in QGIS 3.4 using the common method of "Add Layer" > "Add Delimited Text Layer". But QGIS is reading every row of the dataset as a column title, and nothing is in a row below those columns. See the screenshot below:

[image]

I thought there might be some weird formatting issues, so I tried saving the dataset various ways (xlsx, csv, txt) but no success.

Then I tried to create a very simple csv file from scratch as a test, which looks like this:

[image]

And when trying to "Add Delimited Text Layer" with this file I get the same problem. All rows are read as column headers:

[image]

What obvious thing am I missing? It is as if this tool suddenly does not work, though I have used it many times before.

Comment: There is a problem with line breaks. I would suggest to open the file inside a good text processor,  like notepad++, to see what is wrong

Comment: Have you tried "Custom Delimiters"? often when I have a problem opening a CSV, it's because it's not Comma separated Values but Tab separated or semicolons

Answer (score 7):

Most definitely there is an End Of Line issue in the CSV file.
I would guess QGIS is on a Windows machine, and the CSV only has Carriage Retruns (`CR`) **or** linefeeds (`LF`), while it need both (`CR`+`LF`, or `0x0A` + `0x0D`).

A simple fix is to convert all line breaks of the CSV file into `CR+LF`.
Luckily it is an easy operation, and there are tons of options:

- Under Linux use the `unix2dos` command line utility, awk, perl, or whatever you feel like.
- Online there are also scores of alternatives. One I just tried: http://newline.nadav.org/

[image]